# Error C2910. Wrong specialization definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class base
{       
    template <typename RetValType>
    void setTraceFunction(const RetValType* returnValPtr);
};
// C2910
template<>
inline void base::setTraceFunction<const void *>(const void ** returnValPtr)
{     
}
```

How to fix the compilation error?

Comment: Your const chaining isn't going to do what you want here. The specialization argument should be `(const void * const *returnValPtr)` if you want them to line up per your (apparent) intentions.

Comment: Keep in mind the general rule that `const` qualifies the type to its *immediate left*, with the exception to the rule that if `const` is given first it qualifies the type to its *immediate right*.  Reformatting your code using "East Const" style (as it is called by some) instead of traditional and commonplace "West Const" style, you have `(void const* const* returnValPtr)`.